# How to create monthly partition in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a table with 2017 and 2018 year data. Need to create monthly partition on that table.

So I created one non partitioned table and loaded all the data from original table. now I am converting the new table to a monthly partitioned table.

When I am altering getting error as

> ORA-14300: partitioning key maps to a partition outside maximum
>   permitted number of partitions

My Script is

```
ALTER TABLE ORDERHDR_PART MODIFY 
PARTITION BY RANGE (LASTUPDATE) INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
  (
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_JAN VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-02-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_FEB VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-03-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_MAR VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-04-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_APR VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-05-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_MAY VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-06-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_JUN VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-07-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_JUL VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-08-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_AUG VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-09-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_SEP VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-10-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_OCT VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-11-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_NOV VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-12-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_DEC VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-01-2019','DD-MM-YYYY'))
   )ONLINE;
```

Comment: Please do specify the complete Oracle version you are using. For eg;- Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0. I hope you are using 12.2, as this feature is not available in 12.1 Also, you may get a better response if you post the question in https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you ask the same question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52679570/monthly-partition-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong.

First create a **partitioned** table, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERHDR_PART (....)
PARTITION BY RANGE (LASTUPDATE) INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
  (
  PARTITION ORDERHDR_INITIAL VALUES less than (DATE '2000-01-01')
  );
```

Then transfer existing data to the new table.

Either you use a simple `INSERT INTO ORDERHDR_PART SELECT * FROM ORDERHDR_2017;`
Oracle will create monthly partitions automatically based on `LASTUPDATE` value. 
With this methods you would duplicate (temporary) your data and/or you may face a performance issue.

The other method is to use [Exchanging Partitions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-E08650B4-06B1-43F9-91B0-FBF685A3B848.htm#VLDBG1156), should be like this

```
ALTER TABLE ORDERHDR_PART 
  EXCHANGE PARTITION FOR (DATE '2017-01-01')
  WITH TABLE ORDERHDR_2017
  INCLUDING INDEXES;
```

I don't know whether "PARTITION FOR (DATE '2017-01-01')" is created automatically, perhaps you have to run `INSERT INTO ORDERHDR_PART (LASTUPDATE) VALUES (DATE '2017-01-01'); ROLLBACK;` in order to create it first.

You will get one partition for all months, afterwards you can split the partition with [Splitting into Multiple Partitions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-01C14320-0D7B-48BE-A5AD-003DDA761277.htm). Should be like this:

```
ALTER TABLE ORDERHDR_PART SPLIT PARTITION FOR (DATE '2017-01-01') INTO ( 
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_JAN VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-02-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_FEB VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-03-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_MAR VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-04-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_APR VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-05-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_MAY VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-06-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_JUN VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-07-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_JUL VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-08-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_AUG VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-09-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_SEP VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-10-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_OCT VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-11-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_NOV VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-12-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')),
   PARTITION ORDERHDR_PART_DEC VALUES less than (TO_DATE('01-01-2019','DD-MM-YYYY'))
);
```

Note, by default you cannot drop the inital partition of a RANGE partitioned table. If you face this problem execute:

```
ALTER TABLE ORDERHDR_PART SET INTERVAL ();
ALTER TABLE ORDERHDR_PART DROP PARTITION ORDERHDR_INITIAL;
ALTER TABLE ORDERHDR_PART SET INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'));
```